# LoginError Facebook Sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook sdk to post from within my app to facebook. Everything worked fine in development mode i used debug Hash keys.After review Facebook approved my publish_action permission and app is live.Invalid HashKey error came and i  produced Hash key following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29619771/4468665).Now LoginError is coming without any exception.how can i know what is error?is this from Configuration?
[image]

Comment: Can you put a try/catch in your codes ?. Adjust catch (exception ex) log.i("error", ex.getmessage()) maybe we can see errors then

Comment: FacebookCallback onError returns same FacebookException as shown in screenshot.

Comment: i uninstalled facebook app and i was able to post using webview but this error comes when app tries to post using facebook app.

Comment: i am facing this issue on samsung devices only and with native app only.is there any way to disable login trough native app.

Answer (score 0):

First, is there no error messages in LogCat? If there is, please post it.

I think I've encountered something like this before. And the issue is that the App ID I've used in my Live app is the App ID for the Debug app. Check it Sir.

(Sorry for this answer, I would've just added a comment to your question but my reputation is low to comment)